# implement STL pretty printing using Boost HOF

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, containers, string-formatting

pretty print container of arbitrary type

The following code of few lines provides same output as [prettyprint.hpp](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/louisdx/cxx-prettyprint/master/prettyprint.hpp) in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4850473/2709407),
but the output stream is limited to `std::cout`.

How to rewrite those code using `boost::hof` to provide `print(std::ostream&, ...)` like interface?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/hof.hpp>

BOOST_HOF_STATIC_LAMBDA_FUNCTION(simple_print) = //boost::hof::proj(
    boost::hof::fix(boost::hof::first_of(
        [](auto, const auto& x) -> decltype(std::cout << x, void()) {
          std::cout << x;
        },
        [](auto self, const auto& range)
         -> decltype(self(*std::begin(range)), void()) {
          bool sep = false;
          std::cout << '{';
          for (const auto& x : range) {
            if (sep)
              std::cout << ',';
            else
              sep = true;
            self(x);
          }
          std::cout << '}';
        },
        [](auto self, const auto& tuple) {
          using namespace boost::hof;
          std::cout << '(';
          bool sep = false;
          unpack(proj([&](const auto& i) {
            if (sep)
              std::cout << ',';
            else
              sep = true;
            self(i);
          }))(tuple);
          std::cout << ')';
        }));//})));

template <typename... Args>
void print(Args&&... args) {
  simple_print(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}


//---- user code ---
struct XX {
  int n = 0;

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const XX& o) {
    return os << o.n << "XX";
  }
};

int main() {

  std::vector v                = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  std::map<std::string, int> m = {{"a", 30}, {"bb", 31}, {"ccc", 32}};

  auto t  = std::make_tuple(6, 7, 8, 9);
  auto t2 = std::make_tuple(11, std::ref(v), t);
  auto t3 = std::make_tuple(t2, std::vector{1234, 23, 2, 3, 3}, "abc",
      std::vector{
          std::vector{11, 12, 13}, std::vector{15, 16, 17}, std::vector{19}});
  print(t3, "xxxx", 55, m, std::vector<std::string>{"x"}, XX{66});
  // (((11, [1, 2, 3, 4], (6, 7, 8, 9)), [1234, 23, 2, 3, 3], abc, [[11, 12,
  // 13], [15, 16, 17], [19]]), xxxx, 55, [(a, 30), (bb, 31), (ccc, 32)], [x],
  // 66XX)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding a parameter to pass the ostream would suffice:

```
BOOST_HOF_STATIC_LAMBDA_FUNCTION(simple_print_ex) = boost::hof::fix(
    boost::hof::first_of(
        [](auto, auto& os, const auto &x) -> decltype(os << x, void()) { os << x; },
        [](auto self, auto& os, const auto &range) -> decltype(self(os, *std::begin(range)), void()) {
            bool sep = false;
            os << '{';
            for (const auto &x : range) {
                sep = !sep || os << ',';
                self(os, x);
            }
            os << '}';
        },
        [](auto self, auto& os, const auto &tuple) {
            using namespace boost::hof;
            os << '(';
            bool sep = false;
            unpack(proj([&](const auto &i) {
                sep = !sep || os << ',';
                self(os, i);
            }))(tuple);
            os << ')';
        }));

template <typename Ostream, typename... Args> void print_ex(Ostream& os, Args &&... args) { simple_print_ex(os, std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)); }
```

Now you can use it like so:

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nNCFRWUWndAYshNS)</kbd>**

```
std::ofstream ofs("test.txt");
print_ex(ofs, t3, "xxxx", 55, m, std::vector<std::string>{ "x" }, XX{ 66 });
ofs << "\n";
```

Of course, the old `print` can be a trivial forwarding wrapper now:

```
template <typename... Args> void print(Args &&... args) {
    print_ex(std::cout, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

### Listing

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nNCFRWUWndAYshNS)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/hof.hpp>
#include <iostream>

BOOST_HOF_STATIC_LAMBDA_FUNCTION(simple_print_ex) = boost::hof::fix(
    boost::hof::first_of(
        [](auto, auto& os, const auto &x) -> decltype(os << x, void()) { os << x; },
        [](auto self, auto& os, const auto &range) -> decltype(self(os, *std::begin(range)), void()) {
            bool sep = false;
            os << '{';
            for (const auto &x : range) {
                sep = !sep || os << ',';
                self(os, x);
            }
            os << '}';
        },
        [](auto self, auto& os, const auto &tuple) {
            using namespace boost::hof;
            os << '(';
            bool sep = false;
            unpack(proj([&](const auto &i) {
                sep = !sep || os << ',';
                self(os, i);
            }))(tuple);
            os << ')';
        }));

template <typename Ostream, typename... Args> void print_ex(Ostream& os, Args &&... args) { simple_print_ex(os, std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)); }
template <typename... Args> void print(Args &&... args) { print_ex(std::cout, std::forward<Args>(args)...); }

//---- user code ---
struct XX {
    int n = 0;

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const XX &o) { return os << o.n << "XX"; }
};

#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
int main() {
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    std::vector v = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::map m { std::pair { "a"s, 30 }, { "bb", 31 }, { "ccc", 32 } };

    auto t = std::make_tuple(6, 7, 8, 9);
    auto t2 = std::make_tuple(11, std::ref(v), t);
    auto t3 = std::make_tuple(t2, std::vector{ 1234, 23, 2, 3, 3 }, "abc",
                              std::vector{ std::vector{ 11, 12, 13 }, std::vector{ 15, 16, 17 }, std::vector{ 19 } });
    std::ofstream ofs("test.txt");
    print_ex(ofs, t3, "xxxx", 55, m, std::vector<std::string>{ "x" }, XX{ 66 });
    ofs << "\n";

    print(t3, "xxxx", 55, m, std::vector<std::string>{ "x" }, XX{ 66 });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With your code I figured out what stop me adding the Ostream param was the first  `boost::hof::proj` aiming to implement `template <typename... Args> void print(Args&&... args) {  simple_print(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }`.